# Scrapy contracts 101

Tags: python, scrapy

I'd like to give a shot to using Scrapy contracts, as an alternative to full-fledged test suites.

The following is a detailed description of the steps to duplicate.

In a `tmp` directory

```
> cd /tmp
```

run

```
> source venv/bin/activate
```

activating Python 3.8 and Scrapy 2.5.0. Then:

```
> scrapy startproject foo
New Scrapy project 'foo'...
> cd foo
> scrapy genspider bar example.com
Created spider 'bar' using template 'basic' in module:
  foo.spiders.bar
```

At that point running

```
> scrapy check
```

duly says that all is good.

```
Ran 0 contracts in 0.000s
OK
```

Now edit `/tmp/foo/foo/spiders/bar.py`, then replace:

```
def parse(self, response):
    pass
```

[with](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/contracts.html)

```
def parse(self, response):
    """ This function parses a sample response. Some contracts are mingled
    with this docstring.

    @url http://toscrape.com/
    @returns items 1 16
    @returns requests 0 0
    @scrapes Title Author Year Price
    """
```

The test *will* fail. That's cool. We will adjust it to make it work as a sequel (not this question). In this 101 we'll just avoid the error.

Comment out:

```
# allowed_domains = ['example.com']
```

to let the contract URL (`toscrape.com`) through.

At this point `scrapy check` says:

```
F..
======================================================================
FAIL: [bar] parse (@returns post-hook)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrapy/contracts/__init__.py", line 54, in wrapper
    self.post_process(output)
  File "scrapy/contracts/default.py", line 92, in post_process
    raise ContractFail(f"Returned {occurrences} {self.obj_name}, expected {expected}")
scrapy.exceptions.ContractFail: Returned 0 items, expected 1..16

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 contracts in 0.322s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: servers don't like to be scraped and they may blocks your code. Other problem can be that moder pages uses JavaScript (to add elements and also to detect scripts) but scrapy can't run JavaScript. Servers may also check request headers - at least `User-Agent` - to recognize browser/device and send different HTML for phone, tablet, computer and if they don't recognize browser then may block connection.

Comment: BTW: `scrapy` has special page to learn scraping http://toscrape.com/

Comment: @furas You're right of course. It's odd that amazon is suggested on the Scrapy page, on the chance thousands of us end up bombarding amazon with bots, but no one is going to get flagged simply for running scrapy check from the command line once or twice. It's no different than curl, say.

Comment: @furas But that's all orthogonal to the question. The exact problem remains when using instead toscrape, example, or your own localhost. Ideas?

Comment: you have to better describe what you do - step by step - because I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I finally reproduced problem but if I use `@url http://toscrape.com/` then I get different error - and different error means different problem. I have problem with `@url http://toscrape.com/` because I have empty `parser()` but I would put correct code then it would work correctly. And `amazon.com` gives error `503` which means problem with connection because server blocks reuqests.

Comment: @furas Now I see the problem. Even when the contract fails, that still results in an exception. It's not quite like a test, where passing or failing a test is a normal occurrence. (The failure itself speaks loudly enough.)

Comment: `@returns items 1 16` and `@scrapes Title Author Year Price` means you have to return at least 1 item, and at most 16 items with `Title Author Year Price` - like `yield {'Title': '', 'Author': '', 'Year': '', 'Price': ''}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `@url http://www.amazon.com/s?field-keywords=selfish+gene` I get also error `503`.

Probably it is very old example - it uses `http` but modern pages use `https` - and `amazone` could rebuild page and now it has better system to detect spamers/hackers/bots and block them.

If I use `@url http://toscrape.com/` then I don't get error `503` but I still get other error `FAILED` because it needs some code in `parse()`

`@scrapes Title Author Year Price` means it has to return item with keys `Title Author Year Price`

```
    item = {'Title': '', 'Author': '', 'Year': '', 'Price': ''}
```

`@returns items 1 16` means it has to return at least 1 item, and at most 16 items

at least 1 item:

```
yield item
```

at most 16 items:

```
for _ in range(16):
    yield item
```

`@returns requests 0 0` means you can't use `yield Request(absolute_url, ...)` nor `yield response.follow(relative_url, ...)`

So `parse()` needs code like

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    #allowed_domains = ['toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        ### @url http://www.amazon.com/s?field-keywords=selfish+gene
        ### @url https://www.amazon.com/s?k=selfish+gene
        @url http://toscrape.com/
        @returns items 1 16
        @returns requests 0 0
        @scrapes Title Author Year Price
        """

        print('[parse] url:', response.url)

        # don't return requests
        #yield Request('http://toscrape.com/other_page')
        #yield response.follow('/other_page')
        
        # it has to return item with keys: Title Author Year Price
        item = {'Title': '', 'Author': '', 'Year': '', 'Price': ''}

        # it has to return at least 1 item, and at most 16 items
        for _ in range(1):  
            yield item
```

and then I get result

```
[parse] url: http://toscrape.com/
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 contracts in 0.670s

OK
```